# Multithreading using the boost library

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread, boost-bind

Wish to simultaneously call a function multiple times. I wish to use threads to call a function which will utilize the machines capability to the fullest. This is a 8 core machine, and my requirement is to use the machine cpu from 10% to 100% or more.

My requirement is to use the boost class. Is there any way I can accomplish this using the boost thread or threadpool library? Or some other way to do it?

Also, if I have to call multiple functions with different parameters each time (with separate threads), what is the best way to do this? [using boost or not using boost] and how?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::mutex;
using boost::thread;

int threadedAPI1( );
int threadedAPI2( );
int threadedAPI3( );
int threadedAPI4( );

int threadedAPI1( ) {
    cout << "Thread0" << endl;
}


int threadedAPI2( ) {
    cout << "Thread1" << endl;
}

int threadedAPI3( ) {
    cout << "Thread2" << endl;
}

int threadedAPI4( ) {
    cout << "Thread3" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    boost::threadpool::thread_pool<> threads(4);
    // start a new thread that calls the "threadLockedAPI" function
    threads.schedule(boost::bind(&threadedAPI1,0));
    threads.schedule(boost::bind(&threadedAPI2,1));
    threads.schedule(boost::bind(&threadedAPI3,2));
    threads.schedule(boost::bind(&threadedAPI4,3));
    // wait for the thread to finish
    threads.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

The above is not working and I am not sure why? :-(

Comment: It's always a good idea to specify *how* it is "not working". It doesn't do what you want? It doesn't compile? What errors do you get? Where exactly do you get them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest that you read up on the documentation for the functions you use. From your comment in James Hopkin's answer, it seems like you don't know what boost::bind does, but simply copy-pasted the code.

boost::bind takes a function (call it f), and optionally a number of parameters, and returns a function which, when called, calls f with the specified parameters.

That is, `boost::bind(threadedAPI1, 0)()` (creating a function which takes no arguments and calls threadedAPI1() with the argument 0, and then calling that) is equivalent to `threadedAPI1(0)`.

Since your threadedAPI functions don't actually take any parameters, you can't pass any arguments to them. That is just fundamental C++. You can't call `threadedAPI1(0)`, but only `threadedAPI1()`, and yet when you call the function, you try (via boost::bind) to pass the integer 0 as an argument.

So the simple answer to your question is to simply define threadedAPI1 as follows:

```
int threadedAPI1(int i);
```

However, one way to avoid the boost::bind calls is to call a functor instead of a free function when launching the thread. Declare a class something like this:

```
struct threadedAPI {
  threadedAPI(int i) : i(i) {} // A constructor taking the arguments you wish to pass to the thread, and saves them in the class instance.

  void operator()() { // The () operator is the function that is actually called when the thread starts, and because it is just a regular class member function, it can see the 'i' variable initialized by the constructor
    cout << "Thread" << i << endl; // No need to create 4 identical functions. We can just reuse this one, and pass a different `i` each time we call it.
  }
private:
  int i;
};
```

Finally, depending on what you need, plain threads may be better suited than a threadpool. In general, a thread pool only runs a limited number of threads, so it may queue up some tasks until one of its threads finish executing. It is mainly intended for cases where you have many short-lived tasks.

If you have a fixed number of longer-duration tasks, creating a dedicated thread for each may be the way to go.

Comment: thanks, this seems to make a lot of sense. sorry for not reading up on the docs before posting.

Answer (score 4):

You're binding parameters to functions that don't take parameters:

```
int threadedAPI1( );

boost::bind(&threadedAPI1,0)
```

Just pass the function directly if there are no parameters:

```
threads.schedule(&threadedAPI1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your interest is in using your processor effeciently then you might want to consider intels thread building blocks http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/294797.htm. I believe it is designed specifically to utilise multi core processors while boost threads leaves control up to the user (i.e. TBB will thread differently on a quad core compared to a dual core).

As for your code you are binding functions which don't take parameters to a parameter. Why? You might also want to check the return code from schedule.

Comment: thanks patrick. actually have modified the question to be more specific. i wanted to find something which will let me call multiple functions simultaneously. also, am not sure as to how to send parameters.